# Inner join con nodejs no devuelve un json con las 2 tablas

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, express

hago la siguiente consulta con mysql:

```sql
 SELECT categoria.nombre , platillos.nombre, platillos.precio , platillos.disponible
 FROM categoria
 INNER JOIN platillos 
 ON categoria.id=platillos.categoriaid;
```

esto funciona perfectamente en el workbench, pero cuando hago la consulta con nodejs, devuelve lo mismo pero sin el "categoria.nombre", solo devuelve los datos de una sola tabla.
como puedo hacer para que esto no pase?

el codigo de node es este:

```js
let resultado = await la consulta
res.json(resultado)
```

---

el problema era que tenian el mismo nombre y se "sobreescribian" quedando una sola.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a modificar la consulta poniendo un alias, de la siguiente forma...

```
 SELECT categoria.nombre AS nombreCategoria, platillos.nombre, platillos.precio , platillos.disponible
 FROM categoria
 INNER JOIN platillos 
 ON categoria.id=platillos.categoriaid;
```

Por supuesto, habrá que cambiar también el código donde hacías referencia al campo 'nombre' de la tabla categoría, para reemplazarlo por nombreCategoria.